# Which modelling package currently implements an AI derived force field?

Tags: software-recommendations, forcefields, machine-learning

I would like to use an AI-derived force field as they seemed to have lesser computational cost.
Which simulation package (Gromacs, Amber, NAMD...) currently implement some of them?

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's possible to use NN force fields computed with RuNNer (Behler-Parinello NNs) in Lammps.

Comment: I don't have an answer, but LAMMPS and OpenMM are the two most flexible, and I would expect them to be the first to offer this

Comment: GROMACS was in search of a machine learning specialist a little while ago... not sure how that is going, but they are obviously interested

Answer (score 6):

I don't know the implementation details, and if can be counted as "AI derived force field", but, If you're interested in metal complexes, there's a free software, Python-based tool called molSimplify, that uses machine learning to optimize geometry of metal complexes. From [their site](http://hjkgrp.mit.edu/molSimplify-tutorials):

> Geometry optimization with density functional theory (DFT), a general
> procedure to obtain the ground state structures of a complex, is
> computationally demanding in terms of time and can also easily fail.
> Two main failure modes are 1) the expected geometry cannot maintain
> stable during the DFT simulation (e.g., ligand dissociation) and 2)
> the electronic structure of the optimized geometry is bad, which
> indicates the system of study is out of the domain of applicability of
> DFT. Either case can only be identified after a simulation completes,
> leading to a massive waste of the computational resources (and your
> time!).
>
> To address this challenge, we built machine learning models to
> classify the simulation outcomes and readily achieved a good
> performance on the out-of-sample test data.

For more details, see their paper [Duan, Chenru, et al. “Learning from Failure: Predicting Electronic Structure Calculation Outcomes with Machine Learning Models”. Journal of Chemical Theory and Computation, vol. 15, no 4, abril de 2019, p. 2331–45. ACS Publications, doi:10.1021/acs.jctc.9b00057.](https://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/acs.jctc.9b00057)

Comment: does this actually calculate an energy tho? I think it is only guessing if it will be worthwhile to continue investigations.